# play framework: populate dropdown in groovy template with list/map

Tags: playframework

I am using play framework 1.2.3.  How can one go about (syntax) populating a dropdown with values from a list/map using the groovy templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked - hope it helps.

Controller:
    render(items);

Template:
    
    #{list items, as:'item'} 
     ${item.value}
    #{/}

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the CRUD, it do it automatically. But when you want to do it on your own, I found the tag template in `modules\crud\app\views\tags\crud\relationField.html`

```
%{ pName = 'object.' + _name + '.' + play.db.Model.Manager.factoryFor(_field.property.relationType).keyName() }%

#{field 'object.' + _name}
    <label for="${field.id}">
        &{_name}
    </label>

        <input type="hidden" name="${pName}" value="" />
        <select id="${field.id}" name="${pName}" multiple="yes">
            %{ _field.choices.each() { }%
            %{
                selected = false;
                if(field.error?.message != 'validation.required') {
                    if(params[pName]) {
                        selected = params.getAll(${pName}).contains(it._key().toString())
                    } else {
                        for (it2 in _value) {
                            if(it2._key() == it._key()) {
                                selected = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }%
            <option value="${it._key()}" ${selected ? 'selected="true"'.raw() : ''}>${it}</option>
            %{ } }%
        </select>
```

I'm not sure if this will work instantly, because your controller not extends CRUD. But maybe it works or you have to edit some stuff.